# When using Docker Compose to create three cassandra nodes on the same network, how to prevent them from splitting into separate rings?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cassandra

I'm on XUbuntu, with all the latest updates applied.

I've set up the Docker repo, and installed the latest docker suite of tools.

I've used `apt-get` and installed `docker-compose`.

I've created the following `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.3"
 
networks:
  cassandra-net:
    driver: bridge
    
services:
 
  cassandra-1:
    image: "cassandra:latest"
    container_name: "cassandra-1"
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
      - "9042:9042"
    networks:
      - "cassandra-net"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/cassandra-1:/var/lib/cassandra:rw      

  cassandra-2:
    image: "cassandra:latest"
    container_name: "cassandra-2"
    environment:
      - "CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-1"
    networks:
      - "cassandra-net"
    depends_on:
      - "cassandra-1"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/cassandra-2:/var/lib/cassandra:rw      
 
  cassandra-3:
    image: "cassandra:latest"
    container_name: "cassandra-3"
    networks:
      - "cassandra-net"
    environment:
      - "CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-1"
    depends_on:
      - "cassandra-1"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/cassandra-3:/var/lib/cassandra:rw
```

When I check for the status of each of the three nodes (cassandra-1, cassandra-2, cassandra-3) using this bash script:

```
docker exec -it cassandra-1 nodetool status
docker exec -it cassandra-2 nodetool status
docker exec -it cassandra-3 nodetool status
```

I get the following output:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  172.18.0.3  252.53 KiB  16      100.0%            640dbf8a-13bb-46e5-8b1e-4542ee3352c4  rack1
UN  172.18.0.2  189.34 KiB  16      100.0%            7807001a-1885-41d1-b661-bd6c7e0db239  rack1

Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  172.18.0.4  178.24 KiB  16      100.0%            fe8fb5fe-7342-4eeb-92bb-01a755ecd8ad  rack1
UN  172.18.0.2  263.65 KiB  16      100.0%            7807001a-1885-41d1-b661-bd6c7e0db239  rack1

Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  172.18.0.3  178.2 KiB   16      100.0%            640dbf8a-13bb-46e5-8b1e-4542ee3352c4  rack1
UN  172.18.0.2  263.65 KiB  16      100.0%            7807001a-1885-41d1-b661-bd6c7e0db239  rack1
```

I expected to see each node seeing all three addresses (172.18.0.2, 3, 4), but each node only 'sees' one other node, not the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem using Docker Compose to start nodes on a local environment.

I sort of solved it by a combination of:

- [Controlling the startup order of the nodes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) in the Compose file, such that Compose first makes sure that the seed node `cassandra-1` is up and *healthy*, then starts `cassandra-2` and also makes sure that `cassandra-2` node is up and *healthy*, then starts `cassandra-3`, and so on. Basically, preventing nodes from all starting *simultaneously*, especially the nodes after the seed node. When nodes are started *simultaneously* with Compose, it can lead to errors such as a conflict with token ranges, causing some of the nodes to fail to join the cluster.
- Using a [Snitch](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archSnitchesAbout.html) configuration that more resembles your production environment, which is usually when a multi-node or multi-cluster or multi-datacenter becomes necessary. For example, you can use a [GossipingPropertyFileSnitch](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archsnitchGossipPF.html), which is also the same Snitch type used in the Cassandra tutorial for [Initializing a multiple node cluster (multiple datacenters)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/initialize/initMultipleDS.html).
- Explicitly setting the `CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME` and `CASSANDRA_DC` environment variables, which correspondingly sets the `cluster_name` on the `cassandra.yaml` config and the `dc` option on the `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file. This allows you explicitly tell the nodes to join the *same* datacenter and cluster. These options are only relevant for `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch`.

With that, here's a modified version of your Compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.3"

networks:
  cassandra-net:
    driver: bridge

services:

  cassandra-1:
    image: "cassandra:latest"  # cassandra:4.1.3
    container_name: "cassandra-1"
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
      - 9042:9042
    networks:
      - cassandra-net
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true       # default
      - CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0  # default
      - CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS=auto  # default, use IP addr of container # = CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=my-cluster
      - CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
      - CASSANDRA_DC=my-datacenter-1
    volumes:
      - cassandra-node-1:/var/lib/cassandra:rw
    restart:
      on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "nodetool status"]
      interval: 2m
      start_period: 2m
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  cassandra-2:
    image: "cassandra:latest"  # cassandra:4.1.3
    container_name: "cassandra-2"
    ports:
      - 9043:9042
    networks:
      - cassandra-net
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true       # default
      - CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0  # default
      - CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS=auto  # default, use IP addr of container # = CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=my-cluster
      - CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
      - CASSANDRA_DC=my-datacenter-1
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-1
    depends_on:
      cassandra-1:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - cassandra-node-2:/var/lib/cassandra:rw
    restart:
      on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "nodetool status"]
      interval: 2m
      start_period: 2m
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  cassandra-3:
    image: "cassandra:latest"  # cassandra:4.1.3
    container_name: "cassandra-3"
    ports:
      - 9044:9042
    networks:
      - cassandra-net
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true       # default
      - CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0  # default
      - CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS=auto  # default, use IP addr of container # = CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=my-cluster
      - CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
      - CASSANDRA_DC=my-datacenter-1
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-1
    depends_on:
      cassandra-2:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - cassandra-node-3:/var/lib/cassandra:rw
    restart:
      on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "nodetool status"]
      interval: 2m
      start_period: 2m
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

volumes:
  cassandra-node-1:
  cassandra-node-2:
  cassandra-node-3:
```

The main thing here are the [`healthcheck`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) blocks

```yaml
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "nodetool status"]
      interval: 2m
      start_period: 2m
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
```

...and the updated `depends_on` on each node

```
    depends_on:
      cassandra-2:
        condition: service_healthy
```

The modified Compose sets `cassandra-3` to *only* start when `cassandra-2` is healthy, and to *only* start `cassandra-2` when `cassandra-1` is healthy. In that Compose file:

- Call `nodetool status` after 2 minutes (to give time for the node to bootup/bootstrap)
- If it responds in <10s and the exit code is 0, the node is to be considered healthy
- Repeat the check every 2m and for 3 times

If you poll `docker container ls`, you'll see something like this:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              ...   STATUS                                  PORTS       NAMES
bce16c1b0de4   cassandra:latest   ...   Up About a minute (health: starting)    ...         cassandra-2
697fb8559c3c   cassandra:latest   ...   Up 3 minutes (healthy)                  ...         cassandra-1
```

...while the nodes start 1 by 1. In that example above, `cassandra-3` is waiting for `cassandra-2` to be "(healthy)" before starting, which is why you don't see it yet.

Using `nodetool status` is not the best healthcheck, but it works at least for waiting for the node to finish bootstrapping. You can improve it by maybe parsing the output and making sure the node is in the list as `UN`. The `2m` interval/period is also arbitrary, set whatever's suitable on your system and depending on your `test`.

There's also some extra env vars in there

```
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true       # default
      - CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0  # default
      - CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS=auto  # default, use IP addr of container # = CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS
```

...which may not be needed, since those are already the defaults on the `cassandra` Docker image (see section on [Configuring Cassandra](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra) from the Dockerhub page. Basically, those explicitly set the IP address of the containers to be both the listen and broadcast address. I'm just noting it here in case the defaults change.

Finally, in our environment, if you are running all the nodes in the *same* machine, you need to specify different ports for each of them:

```yaml
  cassandra-1:
    ...
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
      - 9042:9042

  cassandra-2:
    ...
    ports:
      - 9043:9042

  cassandra-3:
    ...
    ports:
      - 9044:9042
```

...otherwise, the containers may not start correctly.

If all goes well:

```
$ docker container ls 
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                                 PORTS                                                                          NAMES
4f9f7459f8d5   cassandra:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago   Up About a minute (health: starting)   7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9044->9042/tcp                      cassandra-3
05225ba91e5d   cassandra:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes (healthy)                 7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9043->9042/tcp                      cassandra-2
ca2882224274   cassandra:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes (healthy)                 7001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7000->7000/tcp, 7199/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp, 9160/tcp   cassandra-1
```

```
$ docker exec cassandra-1 nodetool status
Datacenter: my-datacenter-1
===========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  172.27.0.4  70.22 KiB   16      76.0%             5a4908f1-6e6f-42b1-88f2-8d5c6290b361  rack1
UN  172.27.0.3  75.19 KiB   16      59.3%             7060719b-d1db-4177-a2c3-1897320e6e33  rack1
UN  172.27.0.2  109.41 KiB  16      64.7%             94345229-fd00-424d-b16c-e1556fae7849  rack1
```

```
$ docker exec cassandra-2 nodetool status
Datacenter: my-datacenter-1
===========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  172.27.0.4  70.22 KiB   16      76.0%             5a4908f1-6e6f-42b1-88f2-8d5c6290b361  rack1
UN  172.27.0.3  75.19 KiB   16      59.3%             7060719b-d1db-4177-a2c3-1897320e6e33  rack1
UN  172.27.0.2  109.41 KiB  16      64.7%             94345229-fd00-424d-b16c-e1556fae7849  rack1
```

```
$ docker exec cassandra-3 nodetool status
Datacenter: my-datacenter-1
===========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  172.27.0.4  70.22 KiB   16      76.0%             5a4908f1-6e6f-42b1-88f2-8d5c6290b361  rack1
UN  172.27.0.3  75.19 KiB   16      59.3%             7060719b-d1db-4177-a2c3-1897320e6e33  rack1
UN  172.27.0.2  109.41 KiB  16      64.7%             94345229-fd00-424d-b16c-e1556fae7849  rack1
```

The main problem with this is that **starting the nodes takes a long time**. In that sample Compose file where `healthcheck.interval` is `2m`, it takes about ~5mins for all 3 nodes to properly start-up.

Comment: If I take one node down, the other nodes (even after 45 minutes) still list all nodes in the ring. Is another Cassandra environment setting still missing to ensure that a node joining (or dropping) from the data center is identified and added (or removed) from the ring? If so, then it might not be necessary to put such a long delay in the healthcheck.

Comment: @tcs In the list, does it show up as `DN`? The [gossip protocol](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archGossipAbout.html) should detect if a particular node goes down and mark it as such, but still keep it in the list. See [failure detection and recovery](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeFailDetect.html), you can try setting the [`phi_convict_threshold`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__phi_convict_threshold) config.

Comment: Though I thought all nodes were listed as UN; I needed to try again to verify. I found that the down server shows in the list as DN. This is expected behavior. One other issue is that I found at random times during the startup process, a node can crash. I've added "restart: on-failure" - this fixes the issue.